# Why is the unit vector of the angle in spherical or cylindrical coordinates a straight line?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Why are you allowed to define the unit vector of the angle $\theta$ in either cylindrical or spherical coordinates to be a straight line? Shouldn't the unit vector be curved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Vector are straight lines. In fact the polar coordinates is just a rotated regular Cartesian coordinate system. The unit vector in the $\theta$ direction is a tangent to the circle/sphere of radius 1.

Comment: Cannot a vector be a curved line?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector